# How to - auto retrieve SF project when oppening VS code?

Tags: salesforce, apex

The feature i'm looking for - Every time i open my sf project file in vs code, the command - "SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org" will happen automatically.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto retrieve when opening a Salesforce project in VSCode:

1. Ctr + shift + p   Search for the: ‘Tasks: Configure Task’:

a.  Press :

[image: 1]

b.  Then:

[image: 2]

2. Add this task to the ‘Tasks’ list:

{
"label": "Run Retrieve Manifest From Org on startup",
"type": "shell",
"command": "sfdx force:source:retrieve -x manifest/package.xml",
"windows": {
"command": "sfdx force:source:retrieve -x manifest/package.xml"
},
"presentation": {
"reveal": "always",
"panel": "new"
},
"runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen" }
}

a.  Should look similar to this: [image: 3]

3. Enable Automatic tasks for this project:

a.  Ctr + shift + p  Tasks: Allow automatic Tasks in Folder

[image: 4]

b.  Enable it.

4. Reopen the project & u should see this running in the terminal:

[image: 5]